# Not able to generate output when Kannada is used in Beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex, output, document

The document (and beamer also) includes Kannada as the main language and English as the other language. I am able to generate a document file (through XeLatex) successfully. But when I try to generate a presentation (Beamer). `"Package polyglossia Error: The current latin font NotoSansKannada(0) does not" error is generated.` Help needed in this regard!
(Note: Editor used is: TEXMAKER)

MWE of document (this is successfully getting generated) is given below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\kannadafont{Noto Sans Kannada}[Script=Kannada]
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Kannada]{kannada}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\begin{document}
ಇದು ನನ್ನ ಮೊದಲನೆಯ ಕನ್ನಡ ಲೇಟೆಕ್‌ ಫೈಲ್. ೧ ಮತ್ತು ೨ನೇ ವಿಷಯ ಹೇಗೆ ಬರುತ್ತದೆಯೆಂದು ನೋಡೋಣ. 
\textenglish{\textcolor{blue}{\Large This is a testing message}}
\section{ಮುಂದಿನ ಭಾಗ}
ನಾನು ಮೊನ್ನೆ ಮೈಸೂರಿಗೆ ಹೋಗಿದ್ದೆ.
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textcolor{red}{ಮೊದಲನೆಯದ್ದು}
\item \textcolor{blue}{\Huge ಎರಡನೆಯದ್ದು}
\item {\large ಮೂರನೆಯದ್ದು}
\item ನಾಲ್ಕನೆಯದ್ದು
\end{enumerate}
\textenglish{\textcolor{cyan}{\Huge This is another testing message}}
\end{document}
```

MWE of presentation (through beamer) (this is generating error and hence is not able to generate the output) is given below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\kannadafont{Noto Sans Kannada}[Script=Kannada]
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Kannada]{kannada}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{First frame}
\begin{block}{First block}
ಇದು ನನ್ನ ಮೊದಲನೆಯ ಕನ್ನಡ ಲೇಟೆಕ್‌ ಫೈಲ್. ೧ ಮತ್ತು ೨ನೇ ವಿಷಯ ಹೇಗೆ ಬರುತ್ತದೆಯೆಂದು ನೋಡೋಣ. 
\textenglish{\textcolor{blue}{\Large This is a testing message}}
\section{ಮುಂದಿನ ಭಾಗ}
ನಾನು ಮೊನ್ನೆ ಮೈಸೂರಿಗೆ ಹೋಗಿದ್ದೆ.
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textcolor{red}{ಮೊದಲನೆಯದ್ದು}
\item \textcolor{blue}{\Huge ಎರಡನೆಯದ್ದು}
\item {\large ಮೂರನೆಯದ್ದು}
\item ನಾಲ್ಕನೆಯದ್ದು
\end{enumerate}
\textenglish{\textcolor{cyan}{\Huge This is another testing message}}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the article and beamer class is that beamer normally uses sans serif fonts.

You can specify the fonts for sans serif text like this:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\kannadafont{Noto Sans Kannada}[Script=Kannada]

\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\newfontfamily\kannadafontsf{Noto Sans Kannada}

\setmainlanguage[numerals=Kannada]{kannada}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{\textenglish{First frame}}
\begin{block}{\textenglish{First block}}
ಇದು ನನ್ನ ಮೊದಲನೆಯ ಕನ್ನಡ ಲೇಟೆಕ್‌ ಫೈಲ್. ೧ ಮತ್ತು ೨ನೇ ವಿಷಯ ಹೇಗೆ ಬರುತ್ತದೆಯೆಂದು ನೋಡೋಣ. 
\textenglish{\textcolor{blue}{\Large This is a testing message}}
\section{ಮುಂದಿನ ಭಾಗ}
ನಾನು ಮೊನ್ನೆ ಮೈಸೂರಿಗೆ ಹೋಗಿದ್ದೆ.
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textcolor{red}{ಮೊದಲನೆಯದ್ದು}
\item \textcolor{blue}{\Huge ಎರಡನೆಯದ್ದು}
\item {\large ಮೂರನೆಯದ್ದು}
\item ನಾಲ್ಕನೆಯದ್ದು
\end{enumerate}
\textenglish{\textcolor{cyan}{\Huge This is another testing message}}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I try to run the above the following error is generated
"!Package fontspec Error: The font "Noto Sans" cannot be found." 
Kindly help

Comment: @KiranKU The font needs to be installed on your computer. How to do this will depend on which operating system you use. If you don't want to change the font for the English text, you could remove the line `\setsansfont{Noto Sans}`. I only added it to get a consistent look and avoid mixing different font families on the same slide.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.

Comment: In case if "Noto Sans" font has to be installed, can you please guide me on how to do it? I am using MacBook Pro running on Venture 13.3.1 (a). LaTeX is run on TeX MAKER editor and MIKTEX.

Comment: @KiranKU You can download the font from https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans Unzip it, double click on the noto sans file and mac will install the font in the Font Book.app

Comment: @KiranKU Off-topic: why are you using miktex on a mac? I would suggest texlive. This is much more commonly used, better tested and has much less packaging errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Windows** with **texlive** try

\newfontfamily\kannadafont{NotoSansKannada.ttf}[Script=Kannada]

or

\newfontfamily\kannadafont{NotoSansKannada-Regular.ttf}[Script=Kannada]